# Sex, Crime and Functional Analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

Ever since a friend told me about this book titled *Sex, Crime and Functional Analysis: Part I. Functional Analysis*, I have been looking for a copy of this book, but in vain.

SO does this book actually exist or is it just a joke? If it does exist I am pretty sure someone on Math.SE has read it.

GEdgar said the book might exist on the shelf of UCLA library but as pointed out by Nate, the library catalog does not contain such an entry.

Anybody from UCLA here?

Comment: The author is J.D. Stein if it may help (it is a self-published book) [google search](http://www.google.fr/#hl=fr&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=stein+%22Sex%2C+Crime+and+Functional+Analysis%22&oq=stein+%22Sex%2C+Crime+and+Functional+Analysis%22&gs_l=hp.3...1028.3334.0.3596.9.9.0.0.0.0.152.1012.4j5.9.0...0.0...1c.PFdYLBpzrks&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=645b66a3b700bbbd&biw=1041&bih=952)

Comment: "On the shelf in the UCLA math library" ... (reference: Mathematical Aporcrypha, S. Krantz)

Comment: @GEdgar Oh, so this book does exist. Great!

Comment: However, I can't find it in a search of UCLA's [library catalog](http://www.library.ucla.edu/).  :-(

Comment: @NateEldredge Bad news...I did a search myself...No such entry

Comment: Good to see a comma in the title of the book.

Comment: Seems like [someone on Google Answers](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=348457) was trying to track down the author of that book back in 2004.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close the question I just write my own answer here. I still cannot find the question. Apparently the book once existed in UCLA lib for a while but then disappeared in their catalog somehow.